# Using Eclipse preferences to color text; How to programatically access Eclipse syntax coloring preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, formatting, preferences

I'd like to present Java Code in an Eclipse plugin with colors and formatting just like in Eclipse.

However, I want the styling of my text presentation to be the same as the user has it set up for themselves in Eclipse.

The trick is to know how to access the preferences in Java so I could then use them in my code.

Does anyone know how to do this or have any leads?

Answer (score 0):

This file:
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs

has workspace settings that you can look through.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you have in mind for me to look for?